# Automated “Staged rollout” on Google Play Developer?

Tags: deployment, google-play

Is it possible to automate this process? I'd like to set up, say, 10% rollout initially, 20% next day etc until 100%. Is it possible without necessity to log in each time and adjust "staged rollout" value manually?